# Getting Runtime Error in DP implementation of problem : 'Partitioning an array in k groups keeping the max sum minimum'

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, dynamic-programming

I came across a problem in which an array with 'N' elements has to be grouped into 'K' number of contiguous subarrays or groups, such that the maximum of sum values among all the groups is minimised.
Eg : array - 1 2 3 4 5 and groups=3;
then the groups would be {1,2,3},{4}&{5} and the max value is 1+2+3=6.

I have tried to solve this question using dp.The function I created goes like this

```
int minimise(int arr[],int dp[][1001],int ind,int n,int val,int k,int sum){
    int i,ans1=INT_MAX,ans,val1;

    if(k==0){
        return sum;
    }
    if(dp[ind][k] != 0){
        return max(val,dp[ind][k]);
    }

    for(i=ind;i<n-1;i++){
        val1=arr[i+1];
        sum-=arr[i];
        k,val;
        if(k>n-1-i)break;
        dp[i][k]=minimise(arr,dp,i+1,n,val1,k-1,sum);
        int p=dp[i][k];
        ans=max(val,dp[i][k]);
        ans1=min(ans1,ans);
        val+=val1;
    }
    return ans1;
}
```

Initially the values have been passed as: ind=0;n=0;val=arr[0];k=no.ofgroups-1;sum=sum of all elements of the array.

It works for the sample cases i put in, but is giving Runtime Error (SIGSEGV) on submission. Tried reducing the size of dp[][], still doesnt work.

Comment: `IL(i,ind,n-1){` -- What is this supposed to be?  Is it one of those awful abbreviations used for "competitive programing"?  You should post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for that. Well, it was just a for loop.